# Is a career counselor worth it for successful individuals?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, career-development, tech-industry

Although my question pertains to my unique situation, I want to ask it in a way that can help a significantly larger group of people.

When is it worth pursuing a career counselor? What considerations should one make when deciding if a career counselor is right for them?

Here is some context for my personal situation. I am a young adult (age is 18-20) who is very successful in my industry. The industry is tech-related and if it matters, I am located in the United States.

- I have a unique talent that has allowed me to learn a significant amount of the skills required in my industry in a short period of time. During high school, I learned skills seen in most senior individuals in my industry. This has allowed me to gain a significant edge in my professional career.
- I have held several internships and now am working full-time at a mid-level position in a very large tech company located in the Bay Area.
- I have published and presented my research at several major conferences for my industry.
- I have established a public brand around my name and my work. This is partially why I created a new account to ask this question.

I believe that if I continue on the path I am on, I can continue my success. My concern has been though in the past year I have gotten significantly more busy and often times feel that I cannot dedicate enough attention to my career growth. I am concerned that there may be opportunities I can set myself up for in the future that I may not recognize. There may even be opportunities I have now that I have not pursued or even been aware of.

I typically see career counselors being used by individuals who may not be as successful in their career. I am curious though, for someone at a very young age and already wildly successful in my industry, what can I do to maximize the opportunities I have now and especially the long-term? Would a career counselor be worth it?

I am not necessarily looking for someone to tell me what to do (although suggestions from a counselor would be considered). I am more interested in ensuring that I am aware of opportunities in the long-term that I can start preparing/setting up for now.

This question again is not just intended for me, but if you could have an addendum addressing my specific situation it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Kilisi I would like to be aware of what opportunities there are now and for the long-term given my unique situation. Additionally, I think there are opportunities down the line I can start preparing for today.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the idea of someone who is so successful and knowledgeable that they feel they don't need a career counsellor, but does feel the need to ask random strangers on the internet for career advice.

Comment: @Kilisi Although the question cites my specific circumstance, I think it's an interesting question because I have often seen career counseling focused around helping those that may not be as fortunate. I would be happy to make the question more specific if you have a suggestion on how I may do that.

Comment: @DJClayworth I am confused by your comment. I never said I don't need a career counselor? I am trying to figure out if it is worth pursuing one given my position. I ask random internet strangers because even if I am skilled in my industry, that does not mean I am experienced with career development. I am sure there is a significantly more qualified "random stranger" who could comment on career-specific questions like this.

Comment: "think things through with a focused end goal in mind" - that's exactly it, I do not have a "focused end goal". A career counselor could potentially reveal opportunities down the line that I can start focusing/pursuing. I have not made up my mind of where I want my career to go, instead I am focusing on creating as many opportunities I can for myself.

Comment: I mean, what's the harm in trying one out? Either it's useful or it's not but in either event it's a new experience for ya!

Comment: This reads like a submarine advert...

Comment: Soundslike you already have rich parents so you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

What is the difference between the master tradesmen, who‘s worked for many years and the wizz kid apprentice, who‘s handy skills match the masters in every way?

Why does the master earn more, and seen more valuable, when the apprentice is cheaper and arguably skill wise, better?

The Master has experience and knows how to predict failure.

The master will know when something is going wrong ahead of time, and what to do to avoid it....and when they can‘t they‘ll know how to hide it.

I‘m not sure what specific tech, your tech industry is, but if you‘re as successful as you are, but can‘t see what is in front of you, you appear to simply lack life experience, rather than requiring career advice.

You mention you‘ve become ‚more busy‘ and feel you‘re missing out on opportunities...you should find out what is making you more busy, change that, and start *making* the opportunities yourself. Never let things fall in your lap, make them yourself.

The older ones here may not have the technical skills you have, but many of us have decades worth of dealing with people in the industry to have the experience who to ask, what to look for and what to avoid, which i feel you recognized, but are looking in the wrong direction (career counselling) or asking randos on the web. You should be talking to the higher ups (or those more senior than you in skill, which surely there are some.) in your company, what you could be doing more, or better or whatever to achieve your goal.

What is your goal anyways? Figure that out and you‘ll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are a highly successful 20 year old. The question remains if that will continue. History is filled with people who had fame, wealth, prestige at 20, and were washed up by thirty.

We don't know if your skills have long term prospects. Imagine your skills are physical and by thirty you won't have the speed advantage. One piece of advice would be to make everything you can in the next decade, and then coast on the wealth after that. Another path would be to make some adjustments now to be able to continue in other industries.

We don't know what you advice would be.

Is the advice you seek a career counselor? Not one who is used to helping high school kids pick a path. Not one used to helping college kids pick a major and find a job. You don't need somebody who focuses on middle aged workers.

You are looking more for a mentor. That person could be in your company, or your industry. They could be suggested by somebody you trust. If your skills are highly sought after, you could even use an advisor that can handle the now, and a different one to worry about the future.

Answer (score -1):

> Is a career counselor worth it for successful individuals?

Typically not. Most people that are professionally successful are successful because they already have a realistic view of their strengths and weaknesses are and have figured out a way to line this up with their career goals/opportunities.

Many career counsellors will go the "safe" route: they will tell you what you want to hear or what makes you feel good, but not necessarily what you need to hear. Almost any conversation will start with "what are your goals", which could be money, number of people in your empire, size of your budget, number of Nobel Prices or whatever rocks your boat. This is something you will have to find out for yourself.

Highly successful individuals generally have figured this out already and a career counselor doesn't add much value. However, I have seen good results with high level people engaging a coach to work on a specific behavior, issue, or personal goal. But that requires the individual to be aware of the issue and commit to actually working on it.